# How to convert eps file to a large jpeg image

Tags: conversion, jpeg, eps

I am using Linux. I want to convert an eps file to jpeg file. I find that I can use "convert" command. However, the resulting image looks very small. I want to enlarge the jpeg file by -resize option. It seems not to work. The resulting image is a pure black one. Does anyone have the same problem?

Here are more details:

1. If I use:

   ```
   convert -scale 1000x1000 your.eps your.jpg
   ```

   The resulting image looks like a low quality image. The eps vector image is not scaled properly.
2. If I use:

   ```
   convert -geometry 300% your.eps your.jpg
   ```

   I get a pure black image.

Here is my phf file:

> [2shared.com/document/RXl2Be-g/askquestions.html](http://2shared.com/document/RXl2Be-g/askquestions.html)

and my eps file:

> [2shared.com/file/qrmwKegj/askquestions.html](http://2shared.com/file/qrmwKegj/askquestions.html)

Comment: I can't see the files at those URLs.  The service asks me to sign up or something.

Comment: My guess is that the EPS is a bitmap already.

Answer (score 1):

Updated: This should work (-flatten did the trick for me)

```
convert -geometry 110% your.eps -flatten your.jpg
```

Comment: I did that. But the resulting image looks very bad. It seems not properly scaled. Since eps file is a vector image, it should be able to scale very well.

Comment: My test-eps file scales just fine. Care to upload your eps somewhere?

Comment: it still doesn't work with -resample 100. Sorry :-(

Comment: Could you upload your eps somewhere?

Comment: I want to upload somewhere. Do you have any recommendations on where I can upload? Thank you Aioobe. :-)

Comment: Here is my eps file:
http://www.2shared.com/file/qrmwKegj/askquestions.html

Comment: @Anand -flatten did the trick it seems!

Comment: Ok, that file is not vector-graphics. It's some sort of embedded bitmap.

Comment: @Aioobe, it looks better, but still not very satisfactory.

Comment: Okay. I see the problem. I use latex to generate pdf file and then use epstool to convert it to eps file.

Comment: Try converting the PDF file directly to a jpeg image, using either convert or gs :)

Comment: Here is my pdf file:
http://www.2shared.com/document/RXl2Be-g/askquestions.html

It seems not work well. :-(

Comment: I find a solution, but it is by far the optimal. I create an empty latex file with only one line: \includegraphics[scale=2]{askquestions}
In this case, the image scales well.

Comment: I find the correct option is -density:

convert -density 400 file.pdf -scale 2000x1000 file.jpg

Answer (score 1):

[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) can convert Encapsulated PostScript into PNG data:

```
inkscape -D -e "$OUPUT_PNG" -h "$HEIGHT_PX" -w "$WIDTH_PX" "$INPUT_EPS"
```

Comment: Thanks Amphetamachine, I tried. But it doesn't work. Here is my file:
http://www.2shared.com/file/qrmwKegj/askquestions.html

Comment: Inkscape is the only thing that worked for me, as follows: 1)  `inkscape myfile.eps`.  2) File > Export PNG Image...  3) Convert PNG to JPG via `convert image.png -background white -flatten -alpha off image.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

I would use ghostscript:

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -r300 -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile=<output.jpg> <input.eps>
```

Comment: Thanks Curd, it generate an A4 page with large margins. If I trimmed them off, it becomes again a small image.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set desired resolution (in dpi) before reading a file, for example:

```
convert -density 600x600 your.eps -quality 85 your.jpg
```

If you need to resize it to particular resolution then read in high density and then resize:

```
convert -density 1200x1200 your.eps -scale 1000x1000 -quality 85 your.jpg
```